# Loading resources like images while running project distributed as JAR archive

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, awt, embedded-resource

I am having a error for my GUI. Trying to set title bar icon then be included in a Runnable JAR.

```
BufferedImage image = null;
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/icon.gif"));
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

frame.setIconImage(image);
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at GUI.<init>(GUI.java:39)
    at GUI.main(GUI.java:351)
```

The image is in the correct directory which "resources" folder is the root of the 
project file

Comment: I think you  need a `/` in front of resources, check that please

Comment: @Adel Thanks for that. I am receiving another error.           Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null! Same error with change

Comment: And also check the name case, paths inside Jars are case sensitive.

Comment: Use `jar tf GUI.jar` to see what's actually there.

Comment: @JakubZaverka I remove getClassLoader(). same error. maybe I need to change the directory of image since I removed that.

Comment: @trashgod I am only have my manifest and classfile. no images

Comment: Which IDE you are using by the way, or you are doing it manually ?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

First of all, change this line :

```
image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/icon.gif"));
```

to this :

```
image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/icon.gif"));
```

**More info**, on as to where lies the difference between the two approaches, can be found on this thread - [**Different ways of loading a Resource**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/676273/1057230)

**For Eclipse:**

- [**How to add Images to your Resource Folder in the Project**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960381/runnable-jars-missing-buttons/9278270#9278270)

**For NetBeans:**

- [**Handling Images in a Java GUI Application**](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-image-display.html)
- [**How to add Images to the Project**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24821738/1057230)

**For IntelliJ IDEA:**

- **Right-Click** the **src** Folder of the Project. Select **New -> Package**
- Under **New Package Dialog**, type name of the package, say ***resources***. Click OK
- Right **Click resources package**. Select **New -> Package**
- Under **New Package Dialog**, type name of the package, say ***images***. Click OK
- Now select the image that you want to add to the project, copy it. **Right click resources.images package**, inside the **IDE**, and **select Paste**
- Use the last link to check how to access this file now in Java code. Though for this example, one would be using

  `getClass().getResource("/resources/images/myImage.imageExtension");`
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>, to make and run the project. The **resources and images** folders, will be created automatically inside the **out** folder.

**If you are doing it manually :**

- [**How to add Images to your Project**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9613766/1057230)
- [**How to Use Icons**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)
- [**A Little extra clarification**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230), as given in this answer's first
  code example.

**QUICK REFERENCE CODE EXAMPLE(though for more detail consider, A little extra clarification link):**

```
package swingtest;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Gagandeep Bali
 * Date: 7/1/14
 * Time: 9:44 AM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class ImageExample {

    private MyPanel contentPane;

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new MyPanel();

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage image;

        public MyPanel() {
            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(MyPanel.class.getResource("/resources/images/planetbackground.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return image == null ? new Dimension(400, 300): new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ImageExample().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: @trashgod : Thankx for the edit, but Better it will be, if you add your edit on top of mine, since the Java Doc explained that in a much better way than, what I did in my answer, it seems like :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw: Honestly, I think your ASCII art is more legible. :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw  This answer was considered worthy of mention in the [info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for [tag:embedded-resource].  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson : Happy to know, that my answer, is providing the knowledge :-) Thankyou. It's a wonderful feeling, to know, that the answer is liked by many :-) Will try to provide more answers with the same valuable inputs, as I did with this answer. Thankyou again and KEEP SMILING :-)

Answer (score 11):

There's a **much easier way** to load and set an image as a frame icon:

```
frame.setIconImage(
    new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/icon.gif")).getImage());
```

And thats all :)! You don't even have to use a try-catch block because `ImageIcon` does not throw any declared exceptions. And due to `getClass().getResource()`, it works both from file system and from a jar depending how you run your application.

If you need to check whether the image is available, you can check if the URL returned by `getResource()` is `null`:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/resources/icon.gif");
if (url == null)
    System.out.println( "Could not find image!" );
else
    frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(url).getImage());
```

Comment: wrong... it throws null pointer exception if the image wasn't there

Comment: @LasithaLakmal What's wrong? Nobody said otherwise. If you need to handle "missing" images, the answer tells to check if `Class.getResource()` returns `null`.

Comment: +1 because ImageIcon will work like a charm in conjunction with bufferedImage ( because they are siblings )

Answer (score 7):

The image files must be in the directory `resources/` in your JAR, as shown in [*How to Use Icons*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) and this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/googleolympiad) for the directory named `images/`.